# How to use MySQL Connector/NET with C# Application

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

I am working on an old(er) application, which has a connection to a 3rd party MySQL database; the code contains the following:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_oSconnection);
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
adapter.Fill(ds, "DataRecords");
conn.Close();
```

Where the connection string is in the format of:

```
server=<ip>;port=3306;userid=<username>;password=<password>;database=myDB
```

When I run this, the application breaks at the `conn.Open();` line, with the following error:

```
Authentication to host '<ip>' for user '<username>' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user '<username>'@'<myIp>' (using password: YES)
```

When researching the error, the only answers I can find, seem to suggest that it should be fixed by changing the database switching to the less secure, older versions of MySQL/Connector (which seems like the wrong approach) or the suggestion is some variant combination of the following lines, none of which resolve the problem.

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0; 
SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE; 
SET PASSWORD FOR <username> = OLD_PASSWORD('<password>');
SET PASSWORD FOR <username> = PASSWORD('<password>');
```

My application running in Windows 10 is in Visual Studio 2017 (Framework 4.6.1), with MySQL/Connector version 8.0.19 connecting to the database, which is 10.1.22-MariaDB

Would appreciate advise on how to get such a simple connection/query working, without reverting to OLD installations.

Comment: Are you sure the message doesn't just mean "access denied?"  Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to mitigate that, I have given the user "full" access to the database and have tested the same user details from workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this has come with a combination of two items; firstly, making sure that the most up-to-date connector is installed, which was done from NuGet with the following

```
Install-Package MySqlConnector -Version 0.61.0
```

And then making sure that the permissions in the database do not use wildcards. We had the @'%' set to access the % databases (all databases) and was changed to refer to each databse object separately. Really have no idea why it wouldn't accept **% databases**, but after hours of trial and error, this fixed it and we're now connecting to the database, as expected, without rolling back the security (as suggested elsewhere)